# How to change unchecked box errors. (HTML)

Tags: php, forms, error-handling, checkbox, radio-button

I'm designing a page involving selecting components, however, with some components the customer just chooses not to buy anything from there.  This means that one section of check boxes in the  has no value assigned to it.  Upon submission, this brings up the error

"Notice: Undefined index: undefined_index in D:\fileroot\page.php on line 300."

Is there any way to hide this?

Comment: Isn't it better just to hide those checkboxes which don't have any value? Or uncheck them and disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Or an @ before the statement containing the variable.

Or checking `if(isset($variable))` before trying to acces it.

Comment: Don't turn off error reporting, that will hide things you may need. Use `isset`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the @ did it for me.

Comment: -1 Even though it technically works it promotes a very bad practice. Don't suppress errors. Prevent them with control structures.

Comment: So... -1 for just one of the three options being bad?

Comment: @Kolink 2 of the three. Turning of errors is just as bad as using the error suppressor. And the fact that you lead with those two without explaining the consequences or repercussions. I know that's been the *go-to* answer for so long but that's part of the reason PHP gets a bad rap. I think the quality of PHP answers on stack overflow should exceed that of the norm. You'll see this on every other 'how do I fix xxx error in php?' question when someone says "*just turn off errors*"

Comment: There's no shortage of examples on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059393/php-notice-supression-only-certain-circumstances-methods.